# Function argument used as list head variable in Prolog

Tags: prolog, arguments

I am a bit confused about this function definition in Prolog:

```
sample(X,[X|Tail]) :- member(X,Tail).
```

this function checks if X is at the first position of the given list and if X is also found in the tail of the list.

```
sample(1,[1,2,3]).
false.
% because 1 is not found in the tail

sample(1,[1,2,1]).
true.
```

But how does it work? X is the parameter given by the user but it seems to be overwriten by the head|tail extraction from the list. So it seems X new value is the first element in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking too hard. In the first case:

```
sample(1, [1,2,3])
```

Prolog is able to bind X, because 1 is 1:

```
sample(1, [1,2,3])
X=1, Tail=[2,3]
```

Prolog then checks the body of the clause:

```
member(X, Tail) -> member(1, [2,3])
```

This is obviously false, so `sample(1, [1,2,3])` doesn't succeed.

In the next case, the binding still works, but Tail is bound to something else:

```
sample(1, [1,2,1])
X=1, Tail=[2,1]
```

So we check the body:

```
member(1, [2,1])
```

which is obviously true, so `sample(1, [1,2,1])` succeeds.

Now, if you were to try this call:

```
sample(1, [2,3,1])
```

You'll still get false, because in this case, 1 isn't equal to 2, so there's no way to bind X at the beginning, so the body never gets checked. `sample(1, [2,3,1])` is false even though 1 appears in both places, because it didn't appear at the beginning of the list as well.

I have no idea why you'd want such a function, but it is working as one would expect. There's no overwriting of variables happening here.

Comment: Nice answer. +1 for the good explanation.

Prolog is *weird* in some way - you provide both the question and answer, and prolog will tell whether you're correct or not!

Comment: Thanks! I love Prolog, but it is a head trip.

Comment: Me too. Prolog's great actually, and I love recursion :)

Comment: I think I got it. The problem was, that I was thinking that [X|Tail] would assign the head of the list to the variable X, no matter what it's value is. This function is sensless, but it helps me understanding how prolog works ;) Thanks